# Select single value from xml with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I don't really know a lot about xml , How do I select "Hello" or "world" with XPath?

```
<Site>
    <Row>
        <Title>Hello</Title>
        <Bigtext>World</Bigtext>
        <Smalltext>Test</Smalltext>
    </Row>
</Site>
```

Comment: Go read up about xpath and try it out. Here is one site: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp When you have some code, come back and update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the XPath

```
/Site/Row/Title
```

or

```
/Site/Row/Bigtext
```

to get the values for all rows in your site collection.
If you would  like to get the value of an row, use

```
/Site/Row[1]/Title
```

for searching by index, or filter by using

```
/Site/Row[Smalltext='Test']/Title
```

to get all Title values for rows where Smalltext contains Test.

Answer (score 1):

XPath for Hello will be like below. Look at XPath examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp). Nice tool is the [XPATH Tester/Evaluator](http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php) online. Others testers are [here](http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx) and [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/).

```
/Site/Row/Title
```